# How to make modules in nodejs NON-Static?

Tags: node.js, angular, module

I have a application with node js and static Angular Files. I need nodejs to check a request header with an authorization token inside. Therefor I have a module, that checks if the token is valid and if this is the case, the user get access to all the following get-methods. 
This works fine with app.use(the module which checks the token).

But I also need the email address of the user, which is written in the decoded token. This email address has to be accessible in the Angular App. For that I have implanted a get-method, that can called by the Angular Application and sends back the email.

My problem is, how to get the Email Adress in safe way. For now I have edited the Module and added another function. Pseudocode of the module:

Var email = “”;
Module.exports = verfiyToken(req, rsp, next) {

- Get Header of req parameter
- Check the token
- If token is valid, then set email = realEmailFromToken

// This one has ot be there, otherwise the following get-methods of the index.js never get called.
If (next is present), then call next()

Return doesntMatterBecauseIsNeverReached;
}

Now the other function in the same module
Module.exports = getEmail(){

```
//Email has the right value if the function verifyToken was successful once. That is always the case, because if not, then getEmail can never be called.
Return email;
```

}

This works for me, but I think the Module is a Singleton. I see the problem if  User A make a successful call and is in the website. In the next step User B make a successful call to the website and have a verified token as well. Now the variable “email” has the email address of User B. If User A now make a call of a component in Angular, where the email-Call is made, then he gets the Email of User B.

Do you understand my problem? How can I get the module make a instance for each session?

Sorry for the English. If you have any questions, I will answer.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

*Closures* are your friend here.

It sounds like you want to do something like this. Consider `sample-module.js`, that exports a function that returns a function:

```js
// Anything declared here is static and visible across all modules
const moduleGlobalStatic = 'this value is shared by all.';

exports = module.exports = function( a, b, c ) {
  // stuff declare here is invocation-specific

  let invocationSpecificStatic = `this is unique to each invocation - a:${a}, b:${b}, c:${c}`;

  function doSomething( x , y , z ) {
    // do something with a, b, c, x, y, and z
  }

  return doSomething;
}
```

Usage is simple:

const doSomething1 = require('sample-module')( 1 , 2 , 3 ) ;
const doSomething2 = require('sample-module')( 'alpha' , 'bravo' , 'charlie' );

`doSomething()` has *closed over* the variables visible in the different scopes above.

- `doSomething1` and `doSomething2` share `moduleGlobalStatic`.
- `doSomething2` and `doSomething2` each get their own values for `a`, `b`, and `c`, as well as `invocationSpecificStatic`.
- Each time `doSomething1` or `doSomething2` is called, they get their own copies of `x`, `y`, and `z`. However, their `a`, `b`, `c` and `invocationSpecificStatic` variables are invariant on each call (unless they modify them during execution).